# How to manually post data from firebase on my iOS Swift application?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I wonder if it is possible to manually post data from `firebase` on my application. Let me explain, I want my user to send a post in my `Firebase`  database from my application. But to ensure that its publication is not displayed until after I validated it manually. I do not know if I'm clear feel free to ask me to explain again.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very common requirement that is easy to implement with Firebase.

Set up two top-level queues:

```
posts
pendingPosts
```

Your own account can read/write from `pendingPosts` and `posts`. But give your regular users only write access to `pendingPosts`. They can read from `posts`, but cannot write there.

Now your users can write a pending post. You can then approve it by moving (recreating) it under `posts` and removing it from `pendingPosts`.